# Azure postgresql serwer - how to expose via rest api

Tags: java, rest, api, jakarta-ee

I would like to expose my postgresql database via REST API. Database it self is available on azure server. It works, I may connect to it via pgAdmin.

But how can create REST API to it? REST would be useful for me in order to perform some select queries from android app.

In case I would have to create web service by myself, I would prefer do it in JEE.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Disclamer: I am an owner of the product in the answer.</sub>

Hello,

I don't believe you can do this with Microsoft Azure. You might want to check out https://zenite.io, a platform that focuses on creating the bridge between the database data and the REST API using token authentication.

For example, you can create an API endpoint `/user` and define a SQL query on it:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id;
```

and then execute a GET request on the database server:

```
https://server.zenite.io/user?id=1
```

This URL would return the data in the JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "rows": [
            {
                "Id": 1,
                "FirstName": "John",
                "LastName": "Doe",
                "Age": 30
            }
        ],
        "code": 0
    }
]
```

However you would need to migrate your PostgreSQL database to zenite. If you want to do this, you can upload the archive of your existing database using the web portal.

Regards,

Igor